# undefined is not a function zombie.js

Tags: cucumber, zombie.js

I'm new to both zombie and cucumber-js, so I apologize if I leave out anything important. If you need something I missed, please just ask.

I'm trying to get cucumber-js/zombie up and running on my XP box.  I've had several issues along the way, but, with help, have gotten past those. Now I'm getting a new one. I have a test feature file with test files before it (basically pulled from the cucumber.js page on github).  I installed both cucumber and zombie with a -g since it didn't see it otherwise. When I run the command `cucumber-js features\myfeature.feature`, I get the following error:

`<projfolder>\features\support\world.js
  this.browser = new zombie.Browser();
                 ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function`
(followed by a stacktrace)

I.am.lost.

I would greatly appreciate ANY help that ANYONE can give me on this.

```
node v0.8.17 
cucumber v0.3.0
WinXP
don't know how to tell a version of zombie
```

Comment: Oops, I just see now that the carat didn't show up right.  It should be right under the word "new"

Comment: Can you show us the world.js file?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am getting the same error. It seems like an issue of Zombie upgrading from v1 to v2.

Comment: Nope. I moved on to other things and this fell off of my plate. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**I understand that this is coming quite late to the question, and the author may have moved on to something else. It is to help others, who may come to this question**

Hopefully, your zombie is set to this -

`var zombie=require("zombie");`

Having clarified that, you need to change your step from

`this.browser = new zombie.Browser();`

to:

`this.browser=new zombie();`

and that should work fine.

There is a lot more to that, for more help [check this API out](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API).